# X11 Window/GLXWindow attributes to GLFWwindow

Tags: c++, opengl, x11, glfw, glx

Im created GLX window, that contains CWOverrideRedirect attribute, and destroyed input shape, so it looks like OpenGL overlay. Now I am wanted to draw a 2d text or use ImGUI. A lot of examples use GLFW library. So, the main problem is to make GLFWwindow transparency and without input shape.

```
int attr_mask =
        CWOverrideRedirect| //borderless, always on top
        CWColormap|
        CWBorderPixel|
        CWEventMask;
window_handle = XCreateWindow( Xdisplay,
                                Xroot,
                                x, y, width, height,
                                0,
                                visual->depth,
                                InputOutput,
                                visual->visual,
                                attr_mask, &attr);
..............

// Destroy input shape
XRectangle rect;
XserverRegion region = XFixesCreateRegion(Xdisplay, &rect, 1);
XFixesSetWindowShapeRegion(Xdisplay, window_handle, ShapeInput, 0, 0, region);
XFixesDestroyRegion(Xdisplay, region);

if ((del_atom = XInternAtom(Xdisplay, "WM_DELETE_WINDOW", 0)) != None) {
    XSetWMProtocols(Xdisplay, window_handle, &del_atom, 1);
}
```

From ImGUI opengl3 example

```
GLFWwindow* window = glfwCreateWindow(1280, 720, "ImGui OpenGL3 example", NULL, NULL);
glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);
gl3wInit();
```

Comment: https://github.com/glfw/glfw/issues/197